# cURL CMD vs PHP getting different result using --negotate

Tags: php, curl

I have hit a wall and cannot seem to find the appropriate answer on stack (or anywhere else). I am having a problem getting my cURL request via PHP to authorize properly.

**The following request using cURL 7.57.0 via the command line works:**

```
curl --negotiate -u MYDOMAIN\myuser:mypass  http://myip:myport/mywebservice.svc
```

**When I try the code below using PHP 5.6.4 (running on Windows) with cURL v7.39.0 I get a 401.2 error:**

```
<?php
//Set vars
$url = "http://myip:myport/mywebservice.svc"; // asmx URL of WSDL
$un = "myuser";  //  username
$password = "mypass"; // password
$domain = "MYDOMAIN\\"; // domain

//Set Header Array
$headers = array(
            'Method: GET',
            'Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
            'User-Agent: PHP-SOAP-CURL',
            "SOAPAction: urn:MyService");

//Create, Send and Output cURL Request
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NEGOTIATE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,  $domain . $un.":".$password);

$response = curl_exec($ch); 
echo $response;
?>
```

**Here is the PHP CURL Settings:**

```
cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => 7.39.0
Age => 3
**Features**
AsynchDNS => Yes
CharConv => No
Debug => No
GSS-Negotiate => No
IDN => Yes
IPv6 => Yes
krb4 => No
Largefile => Yes
libz => Yes
NTLM => Yes
NTLMWB => No
SPNEGO => Yes
SSL => Yes
SSPI => Yes
TLS-SRP => No
Protocols => dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host => i386-pc-win32
SSL Version OpenSSL/1.0.1i
ZLib Version => 1.2.7.3
libSSH Version => libssh2/1.4.3
```

*For what it's worth, I am trying to connect to a web service hosted on Windows IIS using Windows Authentication with the "Negotiate" provider*

Does anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong?  Is is just the difference between CURL 7.57 and curlib for PHP v7.39?

Any other thoughts?

Thank you so much in advance!
Dan

***************** EDIT ********************

At this point, my best guess is that the CURLAUTH_NEGOTIATE in PHP curlib is simply not doing the same this as --negotiate in the cURL library I downloaded and ran separately via the CMD line! With that said, I think I will start new, more precise and clearly stated question.  Thanks to all who commented.

Comment: Aren't you missing a backslash between `$domain` and `$un`?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I baked the backslash into the $domain var.

Comment: "PHP 6.5.4" - uh, wut? AFAIK the 6.x branch was never released.

Comment: Hi Chris,  oops!  A little dyslexic typing.. I meant "PHP Version 5.6.4"  Thanks for catching that :) Will edit main entry!

Comment: Have you tried outputting the cURL error? Code like this might help: `if($response === false) { echo 'cURL error: ' . curl_error($ch); }`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, e_i_pi.  Unfortunately the issue is not a curl error... the request completes and returns the HTML of the 401.2 error returned by the remote web server. Any additional thoughts are very welcome :)